# Diff more than 4 buffers at the same time

Tags: vimdiff

I often want to diff more than 4 files, but I run into `E96: Can not diff more than 4 buffers`. This limit seems to be compiled into vim, and it also seems rather arbitrary.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

I found [here](http://vim_use.narkive.com/iwfmPcTT/can-not-diff-more-than-4-buffers) that I'd need to change `DB_COUNT`, but that thread is two years old and it doesn't look like they actually tried to implement that fix.

Would it work? Would it break anything?

Comment: Why don't you simply try it?

Comment: No, nothing has changed since then. You need to recompile Vim as I said in the thread mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing DB_COUNT  in structs.h does indeed work, and so far, I haven't run into any issues. Here's the git diff of my change:

```
diff --git a/src/structs.h b/src/structs.h
index 4488bf8..7524bd1 100644
--- a/src/structs.h
+++ b/src/structs.h
@@ -2296,7 +2296,7 @@ struct file_buffer
 /*
  * Stuff for diff mode.
  */
-# define DB_COUNT 4    /* up to four buffers can be diff'ed */
+# define DB_COUNT 16   /* up to four buffers can be diff'ed */

 /*
  * Each diffblock defines where a block of lines starts in each of the buffers
```

Update: This has now been added to Vim in [patch 7.4.2251](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v7.4.2251). However, it has only increased to 8, not to 16. If you need it to be higher than 8, you'll still need to increase DB_COUNT and compile Vim yourself.

Comment: you should have changed the /* comment */ as well, it is misleading this way

Comment: True, and there's also some documentation that needs to be changed. If you want to create your own patch to up it to sixteen, I'd suggest basing it on [this](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/015efc32c1add6269099364835ddf85ff257b3c6) commit.